# homogeneous second order ode solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the ODE

$$4y''+4y'+y^3-y=0$$

has the characteristic equation‎
$$4r^2+4r+e^{3}-1=0,$$
with solutions
$$‎r=-‎\frac{1}{2}‎\pm \frac{i}{2}\sqrt{-2+e^3}‎.$$

but what about the solutions?

Why do not symbolic software like Maple and Mathematica give the solutions?

Is it integrable?

Could you introduce some methods to solve it?

Comment: Firstly, this is a homogeneous problem. Although it is non linear. Also, did you check if your complementary solution actually satisfies the equation? How did you find it?

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh : No definition of "homogeneous" applies to this equation. It is not the case that with $y$ a solution also $\alpha y$ is a solution for any $\alpha$.

Comment: This is the motion of a particle of mass 4 under friction with coefficient 4 in the gradient field of the potential energy $V(y)=\frac14(y^2-1)^2$ without any other external force. It should be physically intuitive that this descends, perhaps oscillating, toward one of the potential minima at $\pm 1$.

Comment: This last change is the strangest to date. Where did you get the $e^3$ from? Inserting $Ce^{rt}$ should give you the reduced equation $4r^2+4r+C^2e^{2rt}-1=0$, which is not independent of $t$ for $r\ne 0$ and $C\ne 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is **not a linear ODE**, so you do not get a linear solution space that you can construct as sum of complementary/homogeneous and particular/non-homogeneous solution. Further, trying to find solutions of the form $y=Ce^{rt}$ will likely not work, and certainly not via a non-existing characteristic polynomial.

What you wrote as complementary solution is not. (That is, yes, it solves $y''+y'=0$, but why not $y''+y'-\frac14y=0$ or anything in between?)

---

Most ODE, esp. those of the non-linear kind, do not possess **symbolic solutions**. If Mathematica does not find a sequence of steps to simplify or solve your ODE, it is unlikely you or someone else with the standard table of integration tricks will find a solution.

**General theory** applies, the ODE is continuous, even smooth, in its variables, thus locally solvable at any point in the phase space. In that sense it is "integrable".

---

The equation can be interpreted as the **mechanical Newton force law** of a particle of mass 4 under friction with coefficient 4 in the gradient field of the potential energy $V(y)=\frac14(y^2−1)^2$, without any additional "steering" force. It should be physically intuitive that this particle descends the potential well, possibly oscillating at an ever smaller amplitude, until it finally ends up converging toward one of the minima of the potential at $y=±1$.

---

Under **linearization around the stationary points** you get linear ODE with constant coefficients. Close to $y=0$ one gets by ignoring higher-degree terms $4y''+4y'-y=0$ which has a characteristic polynomial $0=(2λ+1)^2-2$ and thus real roots $λ=\frac12(-1\pm\sqrt2)$. This indicates a saddle point.

Close to $y=\pm1$ and setting $y=\pm1+u$ with $|u|\ll 1$ results in a first approximation in $4u''+4u' +2u=O(u^2)$ with characteristic polynomial $(2\lambda+1)^2+1=0\implies λ=\frac12(-1\pm i)$ so that indeed the solution oscillates around these stable stationary points, spiraling in in the $(y,y')$ phase plane.

Answer (score 1):

The equation is not linear, and a "characteristic polynomial" is irrelevant. (The term $e^3$ in your post doesn't make sense.)

For small $y$, you can neglect the term $y^3$ and solve the linear equation. Otherwise, this is just a nightmare.